# Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. please check your spelling and try again

Tags: python, flask, url, routes

can you guys help.I am trying to display my flask app in the browser but it shows - "Not found the requested URL".

Not sure that is wrong, may be you can help.

they is no other error in console log but - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
this is my file with the route to different files

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    from data import  name, my_email, site_title
    
    
    pythons_app = Flask(__name__)
    
    
    
    @pythons_app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template(
            'index.html.j2',
            site_title = site_title,
            page_title = site_title + " - Home",
            name = name,
            my_email = my_email
            
        )


@pythons_app.route('/questions')
def questions():
    return render_template(
        'question.html.j2',
        site_title = site_title,
        page_title = site_title + " - All Questions",
        name = name,
        my_email = my_email
    )

@pythons_app.route('/sources')
def sources():
    return render_template(
        'sources.html.j2',
        site_title = site_title,
        page_title = site_title + " - All Sources",
        name = name,
        my_email = my_email
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        pythons_app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my base file

```
        <title>{{ site_title }}</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>{{ site_title }}</h1>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <p>My name: {{ name }} My email: {{ my_email }}</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
    and this is my index.html.j2
    
    {% extends 'layouts/base.html.j2' %}
    
    {% block navigation %}
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/"class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/questions">All Questions</a></li>
                <li><a href="/sources">All Sources</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    {% endblock %}
    
    {% block content %}
    <section class="container">
    <h1>Welcome to {{ site_title }}</h1>
    
    </section>
    
    <section>
    <p>Select a question from the menu to view the answer, select all question to view all questions,answers and
    sources, select sources to view all sources or search for a question below.</p>
    
    
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <label for="query">Search:</label>
        <input type="text" name="query" id="query">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    
    {% if query %}
        <h2>Submitted: {{ query }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
    </section>
```

Comment: Please post the code and html as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: Exactly what URL were you trying to display?

Comment: @TimRoberts i am trying to display index.html.j2 in the browser

Comment: How do you expect us to help if you don't say exactly which url caused the problem?

Comment: @JohnGordon it is  @pythons_app.route('/')

Comment: So, you tried to view `http://localhost:xxxx/`, where `xxxx` is your port number?  Remember that `index.html.j2` is just a template file name on the server.  It's not going to be visible to a client.

Comment: `@pythons_app.route('/')` is not a url.  Show us **the actual url**.  urls look like `http://www.google.com`.